# No NgModule in folders generated by Angular-Cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am new to Angular. I have learned Angular's basic notions and understand the project structure.

But when I use the Angular-CLI generate a basic project, I find in the project there is no NgModule in the root src folder. But accord to the docs in the homepage of Angular, the root was NgModule. So here is my question, what is the difference between them, and why does the Angular-CLI use the component as the root? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think angular-cli has not been updated yet. Angular 2 is still changing fast.

BUT, you can create it easily by yourself:

`$ ng new yourproject`

then navigate inside `yourproject/src/` folder, replace `main.ts` this way:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

now go into the `yourproject/src/app` folder and create `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You may also need to add/update some dependecies in `yourproject/package.json`. Here are mine:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "^3.7.4",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.1"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

its because to date as far as i know Angular2 cli run's on rc4 and not rc5 by the default npm install, the example you see is for rc5 libraries (NgModule)  - and not rc4, you should choose the most convenient version for you, because the release candidate versions tends to update quickly anyway.